# How Symfony works to remove an collection items

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony3.x

When I submit a collection with removed elements, my elements are correctly removed but, I don't understand how Symfony remove elements.

When I `die();` the script doesn't stop into my remover method, so I think Symfony doesn't pass into my method.
So, how Symfony can remove my elements without call my remover method ? How it's work ?

Application context :
I got some data from an API and I just want to add or remove data from my web interface. So, after I've add/remove data, I just want to post the new object on the API and remove the rows concerned. I also can compare the original object (get from the API) on pre submit and the new object on post submit to see the differences between both. But, if a method exist to call the remover of my object, I don't have to use this second solution and I think the first solution with a personnal remover is better.

Example of my remover :

```
public function removeMyElement($myElement)
{
    personnalMethodTreatment($myElement);
    if (!$this->myElement->contains($myElement)) {
        return;
    }
    $this->myElement->removeElement($myElement);
}
```

Thank's for your help !

### SOLUTION

So, thank to all for the help.
I write this lines to help other people who would have the same problem.

By default, Symfony call this own remover. If you want to call a custom remover, add the `by_reference` option at `false` to your collection form type.
`by_reference: false`
More information about `by_reference` https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference

To conclude, by default Symfony call your custom method in this order :
`Setter` > `Remover`

So, if you have a setter and a remover, Symfony will prefer the former.

To solve my issu, I've followed the precedent instructions and I maked my specific treatment into my setter.

Hoping to have helped people.

Comment: Is there any more code involved? How does the rest of your application work after all?

Comment: I got some data from an API and I just want to add or remove data from my web interface. So, after I've add/remove data, I just want to post the new object on the API and remove the rows concerned.

I also can compare the original object (get from the API) on pre submit and the new object on post submit to see the differences between both.

But, if a method exist to call the remover of my object, I don't have to use this second solution and I think the first solution with a personnal remover is better.

Comment: [`register_shutdown_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

Comment: Please add all clarification to the question by editing it

Comment: It's done Nico, I've add the clarification into the question

Comment: You're supposed to give your form collection a `by_reference: false` option so form will call your methods instead. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference

Comment: @emix, it's work with the setters but not with my removers. Do you have a solution or a tips ?

Comment: Either have setters or adders/removers, it doesn't make any sense to have both. Symfony won't use both, it will prefer the former.

Comment: Ok, so I've removed my setter but now, Symfony return an error of type : **Could not determine access type for property "MyPropertyName"**. My remover name is "removeMyPropertyName". Why he doesn't find my remover ? (I just have a getter and a adder/remover right now)